# Gulpfile.js unhandled 'error' event

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, phpstorm

I have this folder structure https://github.com/laracasts/Code-Katas-in-PHP/blob/master/prime-factors/Gulpfile.js
But when i type gulp test in cmd, what i get is
Using gulpfile C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeKatas\gulpfile.js
Starting 'test'...
Finished 'test' after 27ms
event.js 160
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
How can this happen when the location of the .php file is exactly inside the src directory?

Comment: after i test gulp in php storm: Gulpfile.js test
[02:02:44] Using gulpfile C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeKatas\Gulpfile.js
[02:02:44] Starting 'test'...
[02:02:44] Finished 'test' after 26 ms
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Comment: So even if you run Gulp test in command line, you still receive the same error?

Comment: Hello Vlad, i recently installed Ubuntu, and the gulp command works fine, but do you happen to know why i got hat error on windows? And yes, i type gulp and the same thing happened.

Comment: This problem is fixed, i was just missing a plumber package, thanks for the attention.